# SQL Query Combine Multiple Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, rows, case-when

Im trying to run a SQL query to display dates on 1 row instead of different rows and i also need to determine the amount of days between each date displayed.

Please find below the current query.

```
SELECT "Pat_Name",
    CASE WHEN "vw_Schedule"."Activity" = '123'
THEN "vw_Schedule"."App_DtTm"
ELSE NULL
END as Consult,
    CASE WHEN "vw_Schedule"."Activity" = '456'
THEN "vw_Schedule"."App_DtTm"
ELSE NULL
END as SIM,
    CASE WHEN "vw_Schedule"."Activity" = '789'
THEN "vw_Schedule"."App_DtTm"
ELSE NULL
END as PLANNING,
CASE WHEN "vw_Schedule"."SysDefStatus" = 'SC'
          THEN "vw_Schedule"."App_DtTm"
         ELSE NULL
END as TreatmentStart,
          CASE WHEN "vw_Schedule"."SysDefStatus" = 'FC'
          THEN "vw_Schedule"."App_DtTm"
       ELSE NULL   
   END as TreatmentFinished
FROM "vw_Schedule"
WHERE  "vw_Schedule"."Activity"='123' 
or "vw_Schedule"."Activity"='456'
or "vw_Schedule"."Activity"='789'
or "vw_Schedule"."SysDefStatus"='SC'
or "vw_Schedule"."SysDefStatus"='FC'
```

Im hoping for the output to be similar to below

```
Pat_Name | Consult  | Days |    SIM   | Days |  PLANNING | Days | TreatmentStart | Days |  TreatmentFinish

Test Pat | 1/9/2013 |   4  | 5/9/2013 |  10  | 15/9/2013 |  3   |    18/9/2013   |   7  |  25/9/2013
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What results are you getting from this query?

Comment: At the moment i get 6 columns displaying Pat_Name, Consult, Sim, Planning, TreatmentStart and TreatmentFinish. However the dates displayed are on different lines for example.
Patient A has 5 results because they have a result for each column and i want the results to display within the same row

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Some sample data would be of assistance. E.g. what happens if for one `Pat_Name` there is one row where activity = 123 (Consult), but two where it is 789 (Planning). What date should be used? Should this produce one row or two rows? If there were two dates for both 123 and 789 should this produce 2 rows or 4 rows.

Comment: SQL 2005, For each patient there is a date in each column(consult,sim,plan,treatstart,treatfinish) i'm trying to run a query where the dates display in 1 row instead instead so its easier to read. There is only ever 1 activity date per column because these only occur once

Comment: to make it easier to understand the dates are all in the same column called App_DtTm they just have different Activity numbers assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that there is only one row per activity per pat_Name then you can safely use an aggregate function to get the App_dtTm for each activity for each pat_name without fear of missing data. It also doesn't matter whether you use MIN or MAX if there are no duplicates.

```
SELECT  s.Pat_Name,
        Consult = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '123' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
        SIM = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '456' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
        PLANNING = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '789' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
        TreatmentStart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
        TreatmentFinished = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'FC' THEN s.App_DtTm END)
FROM    vw_Schedule s
WHERE   s.Activity IN ('123', '456', '789')
OR      s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC', 'FC')
GROUP BY s.Pat_Name;
```

If you could have duplicate dates for a single activity then it will make a difference whether you us MIN or MAX.

To get the days between activity, you can move the above query to a common table expression (or subquery if you prefer) and simply reference the columns you have created:

```
WITH T AS
(   SELECT  s.Pat_Name,
            Consult = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '123' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
            SIM = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '456' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
            PLANNING = MAX(CASE WHEN s.Activity = '789' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
            TreatmentStart = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'SC' THEN s.App_DtTm END),
            TreatmentFinished = MAX(CASE WHEN s.SysDefStatus = 'FC' THEN s.App_DtTm END)
    FROM    vw_Schedule s
    WHERE   s.Activity IN ('123', '456', '789')
    OR      s.SysDefStatus IN ('SC', 'FC')
    GROUP BY s.Pat_Name
)
SELECT  Pat_Name,
        Consult,
        Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, Consult, SIM),
        SIM,
        Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, SIM, PLANNING),
        PLANNING,
        Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, PLANNING, TreatmentStart),
        TreatmentStart,
        Days = DATEDIFF(DAY, TreatmentStart, TreatmentFinish),
        TreatmentFinish
FROM    T;
```

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the weekends with this statement?

Comment: Hi, so it looks like there are some multiple SIM dates, is it possible to display the SIM dates based on the the cloest date previous to the PLANNING date?

Thank you!